# I want to prompt further field based on its previous field result in Bot Framework App

Tags: bots, botframework, formbuilder

I have below formbuilder code in a class, I want to prompt user based on its response. if user response for field "ConfirmISTTimeZone" is "Yes" then it should prompt for the field "TimeZone" else it should directly prompt "Duration"
How to do this?

```
var formflow = new FormBuilder<FlightBooking>().Message("Tell me Flight details!")
        .Field(nameof(Flightname))
        .Field(nameof(StartDate), validate: ValidateStartDate)
        .Field(nameof(ConfirmISTTimeZone), validate: ValidateResponseOfTimeZone)
        .Field(nameof(TimeZone), validate: ValidateTimeZone)
        .Field(nameof(Duration), validate: ValidateDuration)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `SetActive`method for that on the `FieldReflector`class.

```
var formflow = new FormBuilder<FlightBooking>().Message("Tell me Flight details!")
        .Field(nameof(Flightname))
        .Field(nameof(StartDate), validate: ValidateStartDate)
        .Field(nameof(ConfirmISTTimeZone), validate: ValidateResponseOfTimeZone)
        .Field(new FieldReflector<FlightBooking>(nameof(TimeZone))
               .SetActive(CheckActiveMethod)
               .SetValidate(ValidateTimeZone))
        .Field(nameof(Duration), validate: ValidateDuration)
```

The `CheckActiveMethod` is just a method that takes the state and return either true, if the field is active and should be prompted, or false, if the field can be skipped.

Comment: ok.Thanks, I have one question, the ValidateTimeZone method runs everytime when the formbuilder executes, as i am having DB related code in ValidateTimeZone, I don't want to execute it everytime, as it will increase server request, I want to execute ValidateTimeZone only when the formbuilder is processing the TimeZone field,

Comment: I had a simular problem in the past. First check if the value passed to the method has a value inputted by the user or the default value. If not then he is probably still busy with a previous step. After the value is valid it will also appear in the state so you can check if that value is filled in at all.

Comment: I was having issues with the `CheckActiveMethod`. I found a lambda solution for determining `.SetActive` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44568178/how-to-set-different-fields-on-and-off-on-basis-of-value-of-other-field-in-formf) .This works great because you can do conditionals based on other variables in the class. For example I needed to show a field based on if an other field was true. so i did.     `.Field(new FieldReflector<Account>(nameof(BusinessName))    
                        .SetActive(state => state.IsBusinessAccount.Equals(true)))`

Answer (score 2):

Another option is include 'active: ActiveTimeZone' in the Field of TimeZone

.Field(nameof(TimeZone), active: ActiveTimeZone, validate: ValidateTimeZone)

```
 private bool ActiveTimeZone(FlightBooking state)
    {
        bool setActive = true;
        if (!state.ConfirmISTTimeZone.Contains("Add ur condition here"))
            setActive = false;


        return setActive;

    }
```