# How to set different fields on and off on basis of value of other field in FormFlow

Tags: c#, botframework, formflow

I am using FormFlow to build my bot using botFrameWork(C#). I want to ask user to choose one of four reports and on the basis of selection I want to turn on and off certain fields and ask only those questions which are relevant to the selection.

Follwoing is the enum for report types:

```
public enum ReportType
    {
        Application = 1,
        Emotion,
        AppVsEmotion,
        Help
    }
```

Here are all the fields:

```
public bool AskToChooseReport = true;

[Prompt("What kind of report you would like? {||}")]
public ReportType? Report { get; set; }

[Prompt("What is the application name?")]
public string ReportApplicationName { get; set; }


[Prompt("Please enter the emotion name? {||}")]
public string EmotionName { get; set; }

[Prompt("What is starting date (MM-DD-YYYY) for report?{||}")]
public string StartDate { get; set; }

[Prompt("What is the end date (MM-DD-YYYY) for report? {||}")]
public string EndDate { get; set; }

public string ReportRequest = string.Empty;
```

I have four cases:

Case 1: If user slects **Application**, Then i only want to ask user about **ReportApplicationName**, **StartDate**, **EndDate**

Case 2: If user selects **Emotion**, Then i only want to ask user about **EmotionName** and **StartDate**, **EndDate**

Case 3: If user selects **AppVsEmotion**, The i want to ask user about both **ReportApplicationName**, **EmotionName** and **StartDate**, **EndDate**

Case 4: If user selects **Help**, then i only want to ask about **ReportApplicationName**, **StartDate**, **EndDate**

I tried to do following but it doesn't work:

```
public static IForm<StandardInfoForm> BuildForm()
        {
#pragma warning disable CS1998 // Async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously

            var parser = new Parser();
            return new FormBuilder<StandardInfoForm>()
                .Message("Welcome to reporting information!!")
                .Field(new FieldReflector<StandardInfoForm>( nameof(Report))
                    .SetActive( state => state.AskToChooseReport)
                    .SetNext( (value, state) =>
                    {
                        var selection = (ReportType)value;
                        if (selection == ReportType.Application)
                        {
                            state.ReportRequest = "application";
                            return new NextStep(new[] { nameof(ReportApplicationName) });
                        }
                        else if (selection == ReportType.Emotion)
                        {
                            state.ReportRequest = "emotion";
                            return new NextStep(new[] { nameof (EmotionName) });
                        }
                        else if (selection == ReportType.AppVsEmotion)
                        {
                            state.ReportRequest = "application,emotion";
                            return new NextStep(new[] { nameof (ReportApplicationName), nameof(EmotionName) });
                        }
                        else if (selection == ReportType.Help)
                        {
                            state.ReportRequest = "help";
                            return new NextStep(new[] { nameof(ReportApplicationName) });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return new NextStep();
                        }
                    }))               
                .Field(nameof(StartDate))
                .Field(nameof(EndDate), EndReportDateActive)                              
                .Confirm("Would you like to confirm.Yes or No")
#pragma warning restore CS1998 // Async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously
                .Build();

        }
```

Please help me if I am being too naive. I have tried to follow this: 
[Change Flow Of Message In Microsoft Bot FrameWork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40543581/change-flow-of-messages-in-microsoft-bot-framework)

Comment: Why SetNext is not working?

Comment: @EzequielJadib It does not prompt the user for next field and quits the form with exception **Microsoft.Bot.Builder.FormFlow.FormCanceledException**

Comment: @EzequielJadib Here is the complete exception 'Microsoft.Bot.Builder.FormFlow.FormCanceledException`1' in mscorlib.dll'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Microsoft.Bot.Builder.FormFlow.FormCanceledException` is happening because `ReportApplicationName` is not one of the fields in the form builder.  If you add .Field(nameof(ReportApplicationName)) to the build, the exception will not occur.

You'll also need to use the .Field's ActiveDelegate for the `ReportApplicationName` and `EmotionName` steps, since sometimes you want to skip them.  Returning false from the ActiveDelegate will accomplish this.

Note: I changed Emotions to Feelings in the enum, because FormBuilder was having trouble with the similarity between `Emotion` and `AppVsEmotion` This should get you going in the right direction though:

```
public enum ReportType
    {
        Application = 1,
        Feelings,
        AppVsEmotion,
        Help
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class StandardInfoForm
    {
        public bool AskToChooseReport = true;

        [Prompt("What kind of report you would like? {||}")]
        public ReportType? Report { get; set; }

        [Prompt("What is the application name? {||}")]
        public string ReportApplicationName { get; set; }


        [Prompt("Please enter the emotion name?  {||}")]
        public string EmotionName { get; set; }

        [Prompt("What is starting date (MM-DD-YYYY) for report?{||}")]
        public string StartDate { get; set; }

        [Prompt("What is the end date (MM-DD-YYYY) for report? {||}")]
        public string EndDate { get; set; }

        public string ReportRequest = string.Empty;

        public static IForm<StandardInfoForm> BuildForm()
        {

            var parser = new Parser();
            return new FormBuilder<StandardInfoForm>()
                .Message("Welcome to reporting information!!")
                .Field(new FieldReflector<StandardInfoForm>(nameof(Report))
                            .SetActive(state => state.AskToChooseReport)
                            .SetNext(SetNext))
                .Field(nameof(ReportApplicationName), state => state.ReportRequest.Contains("application"))
                .Field(nameof(EmotionName), state => state.ReportRequest.Contains("emotion"))
                .Field(nameof(StartDate))
                .Field(nameof(EndDate), EndReportDateActive)
                .Confirm("Would you like to confirm.Yes or No")
            .Build();

        }

        private static NextStep SetNext(object value, StandardInfoForm state)
        {
            var selection = (ReportType)value;
            if (selection == ReportType.Application)
            {
                state.ReportRequest = "application";
                return new NextStep(new[] { nameof(ReportApplicationName) });
            }
            else if (selection == ReportType.Feelings)
            {
                state.ReportRequest = "emotion";
                return new NextStep(new[] { nameof(EmotionName) });
            }
            else if (selection == ReportType.AppVsEmotion)
            {
                state.ReportRequest = "application,emotion";
                return new NextStep(new[] { nameof(ReportApplicationName) });
            }
            else if (selection == ReportType.Help)
            {
                state.ReportRequest = "help";
                return new NextStep(new[] { nameof(ReportApplicationName) });
            }
            else
            {
                return new NextStep();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time and explaining in such a clear way. It resolved my issue :)